# In Rails what has default access to helpers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

According to the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html), what does templates mean? Is it all views? Or helpers? Or both?

> The Rails framework provides a large number of helpers for working
>   with assets, dates, forms, numbers and model objects, to name a few.
>   These helpers are available to all templates by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your questions should be answerd by explaining text you quoted from the docs.

> The Rails framework provides a large number of helpers for working with assets, dates, forms, numbers and model objects, to name a few.

Ruby on Rails includes a bunch of helpers, which are commonly needed. As the docs already mention, some examples for such helpers are the [DateHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html) or the [FormHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html). You can find the whole list of included helpers in Ruby On Rails version 4 [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/ActionView/Helpers.html).

> These helpers are available to all templates by default.

All this helpers, which are included in the framework, are available from all views by default. You don't need to activate or include anything. For example you can just use [`distance_of_time_in_words`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words) from the [DateHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html) by adding this to your view:

```
<%= distance_of_time_in_words(Time.now, Time.now + 50.minutes) %>
```

Comment: do views include the partials as well? so the partials will have access to the helpers too?

Comment: Yes, the partials have also access to the in Ruby on Rails included helpers.